# To get Fullpath of selected Folder

Tags: asp.net

In the Below code iam trying to get the orginal path of selected folder.I tried the below code it displays C:\fakepath\10_7_DoxTest.tiff but i am selecting from E:\TestProject\10_7_DoxTest.tiff.Pls anyone help me to solve the problem.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnBatch" onClientClick="document.getElementById('hiddenField1').value = document.getElementById('file').value" runat="server" Text="Create Batch"  OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
  <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" webkitdirectory="true"   mozdirectory="true" />
```

Comment: You can't get the full path because of security reasons, only the file name